# How to view logging.info from Google App Engine?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, logging

I have the following function:

```
@app.route('/db')
def db():
    _, cursor = get_db()
    print ('11111111111')
    logging.info('2222222222')
    return jsonify(x="new")
```

For whatever reason, the `logging` items don't show up in Logs Explorer, I just see the `print` statements which show up with the `default` severity. Where are my `logging` logs going and how can I view them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the level? Remember the default is `WARNING` so you have to do something like `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` before you start using `logging.info()`

Comment: yup that was it, thanks for the tip. Why does `default` show up though, what numerical number is that equivalent to, I thought it'd be below `WARNING` as well, or is `stdout` just treated separately?

Comment: I don't know. I've not fully understood logging on gcloud (it's actually one of the topics I'm currently looking into especially when it comes to using it on ```Cloud Run```)

Comment: See if this sheds any light - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/writing-application-logs#writing_structured_logs